# Heroku log full of POST http requests for "/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml"

Tags: heroku, outlook, outlook-2010

We get in our logs `Started POST "/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml"` from the same addresses from which one of our legit users is making normal http requests to our application through our client-side code. All we find on Google for that url suffix, is that it's probably used for exchange discovery. Our code base doesn't include that string. Any idea why these post messages may be hitting our server from a nascent client device?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have a custom domain set up, pointing to your heroku app? Could one of your users be attempting to set up outlook with an email address that ends in your domain? [From this microsoft article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc511507.aspx):

> For example, if barbara@contoso.com is entered as the user’s e-mail address, Outlook 2010 looks for the XML file in the following locations and in the following order:
>
> https://contoso.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml
>
> https://autodiscover.contoso.com/autodiscover/autodiscover.xml

Comment: boy I should have searched Bing for it I guess... that's a search engine, for those who'll see this question and didn't know.

Comment: do you think this can slow down a Windows machine's browser in making 'regular' http conversation with the application at www.contoso.com? (following your example domain). That was actually the root motivation for exploring this...

Comment: It just returns a 404, right? I don't think 404s take very long or use much computing resource unless you're getting an extremely large volume of them. And in that case the slowness would be on the server side, which would slow down all browsers, not for one particular window machine's browser.

Comment: Maybe IE shares the connection count with Exchange, and then MSFT code decides to throttle or pause the browser connections for a while after all this is taking place. #speculation.

Comment: I've found (with Apache in Linux acting as a reverse proxy) that on our campus network MacOutlook (PC Outlook doesn't exhibit this on the same network) tend to exhibit a very long mean duration (with a very high standard-deviation), which means even though I have a hardwired 404 issuing from a reverse-proxy, the bulk of the time is in SSL. I had tried disabling the DES-CBC3-SHA cipher (which is what the Macs negotiate), but to no avail. I think this is why there are a lot of problems with MacOutlook with autodiscovery...

Comment: If you have Office365 it does this too. I'm not worried about the resources but the 404s are filling up my logs. I can't seem to find a good answer if a 301 would break Outlook

Comment: Anywhere from 1/3rd to 2/3rds of requests to our sites are autodiscover.xml requests. We've put in place special handling for them to reduce resource consumption. Interesting that the DNS SRV record appears to be tried last, instead of checking it first to get directed to the correct location.